# Hilbert Schmidt Operator sum of coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $K \in L^{2}(X \times X)$, and $\mu$ a positive borel measure.
>
> Define an operator of $L^{2}(X)$, $T(f(x)) = \int_{X} K(x,y) f(y) \mathrm{d}y$.
>
> Decompose $K(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\phi_{i}(y)}$, where $\psi_{i}(x) = \int_{X} K(x,y) \phi_{i}(y) \mathrm{d}y$, where $\{ \phi_{i}\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}(X)$.
>
> Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\psi_{i}(x)|^{2} = \int_{X} \int_{X} |K(x,y)|^{2} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

I am having trouble showing that equality. We have
$$
\int_{X} \int_{X} |K(x,y)|^{2} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{X} \int_{X} K(x,y) \overline{K(x,y)} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\\ = \int_{X} \int_{X} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\phi_{i}(y)} \right) \left( \overline{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\phi_{i}(y)}} \right) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\\ = \int_{X} \int_{X} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\phi_{i}(y)} \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{\psi_{i}(x)} \phi_{i}(y) \right) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\\ = \int_{X} \int_{X} \sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\phi_{i}(y)}\overline{\psi_{j}(x)} \phi_{j}(y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\\  = \int_{X} \sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\psi_{j}(x)}  \int_{X} \left( \overline{\phi_{i}(y)} \phi_{j}(y) \right) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\\ = \int_{X} \sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} \psi_{i}(x) \overline{\psi_{j}(x)} \mathbb{1}_{i=j} \mathrm{d}x
\\ = \int_{X} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\psi_{i}(x)|^{2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
which is different from the desired equality, is this computation wrong or is the equality and in either case why?

Comment: The equality stated in the question is incorrect. Simply note what happens if $K(x,y) = 0$ for all $x \in E$ for some subset $E \subset X$ of positive measure. In this case, $\sum_i |\psi_i(x)|^2 = 0$ for all $x \in E$, but it is not necessarily true that $\int\int |K(x,y)|^2 \, dx \, dy = 0$.

Comment: Why is it the case that $\sum_{i} |\psi_{i}(x)|^{2}| = 0 , \forall x \in E$? The problem I have with the equality is that the LHS seems to be a function of $x$ but the RHS is a constant since $RHS = || K ||_{2}^{2}$. This problem is from Bump lie groups Exercise 3.2. The reference is https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~panchish/ETE%20LAMA%202018-AP/lecturesZETAS2018/BumpD-Lie%20groups.pdf on pdf page 33, book page 22. Is the calculation otherwise correct?

Comment: If $K(x,y)=0$ for all $x \in E$ and $y \in X$, what is then $\psi_i(x)=\int K(x,y)\varphi_i(y)dy$ for $x \in E$? And that the LHS is a function of $x$ is exactly why I think it is false. As I said, in my example the equality will definitely not hold for $x \in E$.

Comment: I see. But does $\int_{X}  \sum_{i} |\psi_{i}|^{2} = ||K(x,y)||_{2}^{2}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what your proof shows. The only thing you should probably do is to justify the interchange of the series and the integral in your computation. I would guess that this can be done, but didn't think too hard right now about how to do this.